# Count the number of selected items in multiselect listbox of html using jquery and store that count in hiddenfield

Tags: jquery

I want the count of total selected value from html listbox using jquery and store that count in hidden field so that i can access that value server side.Data are dynamically bind to html control. In output it display 0.

```
    here is my code:-

var rr = $('ddlAssignUser:selected').length;
     alert(rr);

<select id="ddlAssignUser" class="form-control"  runat="server" multiple="true">  </select>
```

Comment: Please share the compiled HTML. And secondly, `#` is missing in `$('ddlAssignUser:selected').length`. It should be `$(#'ddlAssignUser:selected').length`

Comment: Use `$("#ddlAssignUser option:selected").length`

Comment: @PrashantShirke its works thank you

Comment: @PrashantShirke your almost correct but you need to give some space like this in your selector '#ddlAssignUser :selected' and missing #

Comment: @JYoThI Seems you used wrong `@`, and its already resolved so its not worth posting the answer :-)

Comment: @Hinal your almost correct but you need to give some space like this in your selector '#ddlAssignUser :selected' and missing #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to give some space like this in your selector `'#ddlAssignUser :selected'` and missing `#`

```js
$(document).on('change','#ddlAssignUser',function(){

var rr = $('#ddlAssignUser :selected').length;
$('#count').val(rr);
     console.log(rr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlAssignUser" class="form-control"  runat="server" multiple="true">
<option value="1" >1</option>
<option value="2" >2</option>
<option value="3" >3</option>
<option value="4" >4</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" id="count">
```

Comment: thank you for the help .can you just suggest the method with which i can acess this hidden field value on server side.I am using asp.net and in webMethod i want this hidden field count.

Comment: set name attribute to to hidden field on submit of form value posted to server . so you can get . @Hinal